# How can I check if there is an update in Excel file using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Program which will run every 1 hour and check if there is any update in the excel file . If there is any , update the corresponding entry in DB

Comment: You could do a checksum to see if the file has been altered (not guaranteed to be entirely reliable). But to check for individual changes you'll have to parse and check the file.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-a-file-checksum-value-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

Just Check the file.lastModified(), this would return long object and compare it with (current system time in Millis - 3600000), if the last modified time is greater than the above time, than file was updated in last 1 hour and do the processing accordingly.